# What does "DECIMAL DEFAULT 0" mean in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

What does "DECIMAL DEFAULT 0" mean in MySql?

Comment: What part exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @juergend the DEFAULT 0 part

Comment: It means that the default value for that field is 0.

Comment: @user10756823 It states that the default value of the column is 0, i.e. when you insert data without explicitly specifying a value for this column, its value will be 0.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context? In what statement is this fragment appearing?

Comment: The **`DEFAULT`** clause is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual, available here. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html  This link is for MySQL 8.0, if you are using MySQL 5.7 or 5.6, there's convenient drop down that links to the same page in the older documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a default value for a column. When you insert data and don't provide a value for the column, then the default will be inserted, if you defined one.

Comment: If I want to store a year should I use this: "Year INTEGER NOT NULL"?

Comment: If it is only a year, then yes. But if it is a complete date then use  the `date` data type. And you have to decide for yourself if  a column can be NULL or not